# Invalid ARN exception when creating object with Cloud Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-directory-services

I am trying to enter a new object in a AWS CloudDirectory using the organization schema that comes by default.

```
import boto3
#
client = boto3.client('clouddirectory')
#
AWS_CLOUD_DIR_ARN = 'arn:aws:clouddirectory:us-east-1:000000000000:directory/AUaGFp4A7Ea_lY5QwPxSQTw'
AWS_CLOUD_DIR_SCHEMA_ARN = 'arn:aws:clouddirectory:us-east-1:000000000000:schema/published/customer-org.json/v0.0'
#
schemaFacets = [
    {
        "SchemaArn" : AWS_CLOUD_DIR_SCHEMA_ARN,
        "FacetName" : "Organization"
    },
    {
        "SchemaArn" : AWS_CLOUD_DIR_SCHEMA_ARN,
        "FacetName" : "Legal_Entity"
    }    
]
objectAttributeList = [
    {
      "Key" : {
        "SchemaArn" : AWS_CLOUD_DIR_SCHEMA_ARN,
        "FacetName" : "Organization",
        "Name" : "account_id"
      },
      "Value" : {
        "StringValue" : "W000"
      }
    },
```

The `schemaFacets` list has number of other fields that make up the schema. And finally,

```
response = client.create_object(
    DirectoryArn = AWS_CLOUD_DIR_ARN,
    SchemaFacets = schemaFacets,
    ObjectAttributeList = objectAttributeList
)
print response
```

I get a response as:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidArnException: An error occurred (InvalidArnException) when calling the CreateObject operation: Provided ARN is invalid arn:aws:clouddirectory:us-east-1:000000000000:schema/published/customer-org.json/v0.0
```

Whereas, both the directory and schema ARN do in fact exist. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you `applied` your published schema to a directory? I believe you will need to do that before you can create objects in the directory. Assuming your applied schema ARN is `'arn:aws:clouddirectory:us-east-1:000000000000:schema/customer-org.json/v0.0'` then your code should work if you change

`AWS_CLOUD_DIR_SCHEMA_ARN = 'arn:aws:clouddirectory:us-east-1:000000000000:schema/customer-org.json/v0.0'`